# Meterpreter Session over OpenVPN

Tags: metasploit, openvpn

Last month I made a pentesting course and now they opened a lab for us to practice before we apply for the certification exam. We connect to the lab over OpenVPN in our Kali Linux machine.

I'm trying to attack a Windows XP machine in the lab with EternalBlue (ms17_010) using a reverse_tcp payload but it doesn't work. I also tried to attack a Windows 2003 and I can't get session.

I'm using as LHOST my tun0 interface and my LPORT is 4444, I have verified many times and all the remote hosts info it's ok.

Is there anything different that we need to do or configure when trying to get a session when using OpenVPN?

Comment: "it doesn't work" -- what doesn't work? Does the exploit get triggered? Are you able to connect to the machine? Is it only the reverse connection that isn't happening? It sounds like you need to start some very basic troubleshooting steps and confirm each layer between you, the lab, the machine, the exploit, and back again. Can the lab machine even reach the IP you configured the reverse_tcp payload to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the type of thing that is easy to remotely troubleshoot, you should speak to your training provider for technical support.

Besides other users on the network, is there a reason why you cannot use a bind shell. While there are good reasons to choose reverse over a bind shell for production infrastructure a  bind shell mitigates a lot of potential networking problems

Answer (score 0):

Beware, WinXP is `x86`, have checked that your meterpreter was set for `x86` and not `x64`?

Also, try to change the `TARGET`, it might be useful.

And, as wireghoul told you, it seems that you have absolutely no reason to use a reverse bind shell here... a simple bind shell should be enough.